# OpenCL half_ and native_ functions not compiling on Samsung Galaxy S7

Tags: android, opencl

I am trying to optimize my OpenCL code running on a Samsung Galaxy S7 (SM-G930F) with an Exynos Octa 8890 and a Mali-T880 using Android. According to OpenCL-Z the gpu supports OpenCL 1.2 full profile. I have a lot of OpenCL code correctly compiling and running. However, I cannot use any of the half_* or native_* functions such as: half_sin or native_sin. As soon as I add one of them I get a CL_BUILD_FAILURE when compiling the kernel. This is one kernel where such behaviour happens:

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp16 : enable
half distancePointToEllipse(short2 point, half2 ecenter, half phi, half a, half b)
{
    half2 t = convert_half2(point) - ecenter;
    half angle = atan2(t.y, t.x) - phi;
    half cos1, sin1;
    //cos1 = native_cos(angle);
    //sin1 = native_sin(angle);
    sin1 = sincos(angle, &cos1);
    half tx = a * a * cos1 * cos1;
    half ty = b * b * sin1 * sin1;
    //half c = native_sqrt(tx + ty);
    //half d = native_sqrt(t.x * t.x + t.y * t.y);
    half c = sqrt(tx + ty);
    half d = hypot(t.x, t.y);
    return fabs(d - c);
}
```

And this is the code used to compile it:

```
auto program_RANSACEllipses = cl::Program(context, CL_RANSAC_ELLIPSES_KERNEL, true);
    program_RANSACEllipses.build("-cl-std=CL1.2");
    Kernels::RANSACEllipses = cl::Kernel(program_RANSACEllipses, "RANSAC");
```

I have downloaded the headers for OpenCL 1.2 from khronos. Furthermore, I could use the half_* and native_* previously on a different device.

Do you know what am I doing wrong?

PS: I asked the same question on [ARM community](https://community.arm.com/graphics/f/discussions/9610/half_-and-native_-functions-not-compiling-in-samsung-galaxy-s7) but that forum isn't very active so I decided to ask here as well.

Comment: According to official OpenCL 1.2 spec, `cl_khr_fp16` is an optional extension, and it is not ensured in all devices. Check that your device supports it checking `CL_DEVICE_HALF_FP_CONFIG` is present in `clGetDeviceInfo()`. https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/

Comment: @DarkZeros the extension `cl_khr_fp16` is supported by the device. Actually, I can use `half` variables and I do use them everywhere. Thank you for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: 1) what does the build log say ? 2) since you're using fp16, have you tried using only the half_* variants, without any native_* variants ? 3) if replacing all native_ with half_ still fails, quite possibly you hit a bug in the implementation. If i read the spec correctly, implementing half_ and native_ is mandatory, even if they just map on the "normal" library functions (i could be wrong tho).

Comment: This may be an implementation bug. The "half_sin" functions are not subject to the extension mentioned in another comment and thus should compile. Could you check the build error log given by clGetProgramBuildInfo ?